Writing a pure JS function for md4 hashing
I am trying to write a JavaScript script for md4 hashing. I am not sure why the code does not work as I have coded the appropriate endian conversion functions.
The full code is shown as below:


class Md4Context {
    constructor() {
        this.h = new Uint32Array([0x67452301, 0xEFCDAB89, 0x98BADCFE, 0x10325476]);
        this.digest = new Uint8Array(16); // uint8_t
        this.x = new Uint32Array(16); // uint32_t
        this.buffer = new Uint8Array(64); // uint8_t
        this.size = 0;
        this.totalSize = BigInt(0); // uint64_t;
    }
}

// Helper functions for JS endian conversion
const LETOH32 = (value) => {
    return (
        ((value & 0x000000FF) << 24) |
        ((value & 0x0000FF00) << 8) |
        ((value & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) |
        ((value & 0xFF000000) >>> 24)
    );
}

const letoh32 = (buffer, offset) => {
    return (
        (buffer[offset] |
            (buffer[offset + 1] << 8) |
            (buffer[offset + 2] << 16) |
            (buffer[offset + 3] << 24)) >>>
        0
    );
};

const HTOLE32 = (value) => {
    return Uint8Array.from([
        value & 0xFF,
        (value >> 8) & 0xFF,
        (value >> 16) & 0xFF,
        (value >> 24) & 0xFF,
    ]);
};

const HTOLE32_BI = (value) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'bigint')
        throw new TypeError('Value must be a BigInt');

    let byteLength = value.toString(2).length;

    if (byteLength <= 0 || !Number.isInteger(byteLength))
        throw new RangeError('byteLength must be a positive integer');

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteLength);
    let tempValue = value;

    for (let i = 0; i < byteLength; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = Number(tempValue & 0xFFn); // Extract the least significant byte
        tempValue >>= 8n; // Shift right by 8 bits to process the next byte
    }

    if (tempValue !== 0n)
        throw new RangeError('Value exceeds the specified byte length');

    return byteArray;
}

/* Start of Essential Process Functinos */
// Rotate 32-bit integer left
function ROL32(inputInt, rotationAmount) {
    return (inputInt << rotationAmount) | (inputInt >>> (32 - rotationAmount));
}

const F = (x, y, z) => ((x & y) | (~x & z)); // Round 1
const G = (x, y, z) => ((x & y) | (x & z) | (y & z)); // Round 2
const H = (x, y, z) => (x ^ y ^ z); // Round 3

// FF fn for round 1
const FF = (a, b, c, d, x, s) => {
    a += F(b, c, d) + x;
    a = ROL32(a, s);
    return a;
}

// GG fn for round 2
const GG = (a, b, c, d, x, s) => {
    a += G(b, c, d) + x + 0x5A827999;
    a = ROL32(a, s);
    return a;
}

// HH fn for round 3
const HH = (a, b, c, d, x, s) => {
    a += H(b, c, d) + x + 0x6ED9EBA1;
    a = ROL32(a, s);
    return a;
}
/* End of Essential Process Functinos */

// Initialize padding
const padding = new Uint8Array(64);
padding[0] = 0x80;

function md4Compute(data, length, digest) {
    // Check parameters
    if (data === null && length !== 0)
        throw new Error('ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER');

    if (digest === null)
        throw new Error('ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER');

    try {
        const context = new Md4Context(); // Allocate a memory buffer to hold the MD4 context
        md4Update(context, data, length); // Digest the message

        // Finalize the MD4 message digest
        let output = md4Final(context, digest);
        return output;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Error during MD4 computation: ' + error);
    } finally {
        // Clean up context if necessary (JavaScript handles memory management)
        context = null;
    }
}

function md4Update(context, data) {
    let n;

    while (data.length > 0) {
        // The buffer can hold at most 64 bytes
        n = Math.min(data.length, 64 - context.size);

        // Copy the data to the buffer
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            context.buffer[context.size + i] = data[i];
        }

        // Update the MD4 context
        context.size += n;
        context.totalSize += BigInt(n);

        // Advance the data pointer
        data = data.slice(n);

        // Process message in 16-word blocks
        if (context.size === 64) {
            // Transform the 16-word block
            md4ProcessBlock(context);

            // Empty the buffer
            context.size = 0;
        }
    }
}

function md4Final(context, digest) {
    let paddingSize;
    const totalSize = context.totalSize * 8n;

    // Pad the message so that its length is congruent to 56 modulo 64
    if (context.size < 56) {
        paddingSize = 56 - context.size;
    } else {
        paddingSize = 64 + 56 - context.size;
    }

    // Append padding
    md4Update(context, padding, paddingSize);

    // Append the length of the original message in little-endian
    context.x[14] = HTOLE32_BI(totalSize & 0xFFFFFFFFn)[0];
    context.x[15] = HTOLE32_BI(totalSize >> 32n)[0];

    // Process the final block
    md4ProcessBlock(context);

    // Convert hash state to little-endian and store it in the digest
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        context.h[i] = HTOLE32(context.h[i]);
    }

    if (digest !== null && digest !== undefined) {
        digest.set(context.digest.slice(0, 16));
    }

    return context.digest;
}

function md4ProcessBlock(context) {
    let a = context.h[0];
    let b = context.h[1];
    let c = context.h[2];
    let d = context.h[3];

    let x = context.x;

    // Convert from little-endian byte order to host byte order (little-endian)
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        x[i] = LETOH32(x[i]);
    }

    // Round 1
    a = FF(a, b, c, d, x[0], 3);
    d = FF(d, a, b, c, x[1], 7);
    c = FF(c, d, a, b, x[2], 11);
    b = FF(b, c, d, a, x[3], 19);
    a = FF(a, b, c, d, x[4], 3);
    d = FF(d, a, b, c, x[5], 7);
    c = FF(c, d, a, b, x[6], 11);
    b = FF(b, c, d, a, x[7], 19);
    a = FF(a, b, c, d, x[8], 3);
    d = FF(d, a, b, c, x[9], 7);
    c = FF(c, d, a, b, x[10], 11);
    b = FF(b, c, d, a, x[11], 19);
    a = FF(a, b, c, d, x[12], 3);
    d = FF(d, a, b, c, x[13], 7);
    c = FF(c, d, a, b, x[14], 11);
    b = FF(b, c, d, a, x[15], 19);

    // Round 2
    a = GG(a, b, c, d, x[0], 3);
    d = GG(d, a, b, c, x[4], 5);
    c = GG(c, d, a, b, x[8], 9);
    b = GG(b, c, d, a, x[12], 13);
    a = GG(a, b, c, d, x[1], 3);
    d = GG(d, a, b, c, x[5], 5);
    c = GG(c, d, a, b, x[9], 9);
    b = GG(b, c, d, a, x[13], 13);
    a = GG(a, b, c, d, x[2], 3);
    d = GG(d, a, b, c, x[6], 5);
    c = GG(c, d, a, b, x[10], 9);
    b = GG(b, c, d, a, x[14], 13);
    a = GG(a, b, c, d, x[3], 3);
    d = GG(d, a, b, c, x[7], 5);
    c = GG(c, d, a, b, x[11], 9);
    b = GG(b, c, d, a, x[15], 13);

    // Round 3
    a = HH(a, b, c, d, x[0], 3);
    d = HH(d, a, b, c, x[8], 9);
    c = HH(c, d, a, b, x[4], 11);
    b = HH(b, c, d, a, x[12], 15);
    a = HH(a, b, c, d, x[2], 3);
    d = HH(d, a, b, c, x[10], 9);
    c = HH(c, d, a, b, x[6], 11);
    b = HH(b, c, d, a, x[14], 15);
    a = HH(a, b, c, d, x[1], 3);
    d = HH(d, a, b, c, x[9], 9);
    c = HH(c, d, a, b, x[5], 11);
    b = HH(b, c, d, a, x[13], 15);
    a = HH(a, b, c, d, x[3], 3);
    d = HH(d, a, b, c, x[11], 9);
    c = HH(c, d, a, b, x[7], 11);
    b = HH(b, c, d, a, x[15], 15);

    // Update the hash value
    context.h[0] = (context.h[0] + a) >>> 0;
    context.h[1] = (context.h[1] + b) >>> 0;
    context.h[2] = (context.h[2] + c) >>> 0;
    context.h[3] = (context.h[3] + d) >>> 0;
}



The function is called as below and should return an Uint8Array which can then be converted to hex:
let main_string = new TextEncoder().encode('hello world');
let digest = new TextEncoder().encode('digest123');

console.log(md4Compute(main_string, main_string.length, digest));

However, it gives an error output of:
RangeError: offset is out of bounds

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

UPDATE 2: I've successfully fixed the code the perform as expected. This is the final and completed code.
The key changes are:

Removed unnecessary class methods and variables
Adopted the native DataView API for endianess conversions
Rewrote the chunking logic using inspiration from Python code



class Md4Context {
    constructor() {
        this.h = new Array(4);
        this.digest = new Uint8Array(16);
        this.buffer = new Array();
        this.totalSize = 0;
    }
}

/* Start of Round Functions */
const F = (x, y, z) => ((x & y) | (~x & z)); // Round 1
const G = (x, y, z) => ((x & y) | (x & z) | (y & z)); // Round 2
const H = (x, y, z) => (x ^ y ^ z); // Round 3

// FF fn for round 1
const FF = (a, b, c, d, x, s) => {
    a += F(b, c, d) + x;
    a = ROL32(a, s);
    return a;
}

// GG fn for round 2
const GG = (a, b, c, d, x, s) => {
    a += G(b, c, d) + x + 0x5A827999;
    a = ROL32(a, s);
    return a;
}

// HH fn for round 3
const HH = (a, b, c, d, x, s) => {
    a += H(b, c, d) + x + 0x6ED9EBA1;
    a = ROL32(a, s);
    return a;
}

// Rotate 32-bit integer left
function ROL32(inputInt, rotationAmount) {
    return (inputInt << rotationAmount) | (inputInt >>> (32 - rotationAmount));
}
/* End of Round Functions */

function md4Compute(data, length) {
    // Check parameters
    if (data === null && length !== 0)
        throw new Error('ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER');

    try {
        const context = new Md4Context(); // Allocate a memory buffer to hold the MD4 context
        md4Init(context, length)
        md4Update(context, data); // Digest the message
        md4Final(context); // Finalize the MD4 message digest

        return context.digest;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Error during MD4 computation: ' + error);
    } finally {
        // Clean up context if necessary (JavaScript handles memory management)
        context = null;
    }
}

// Set initial hash value
function md4Init(context, length) {
    context.h[0] = 0x67452301;
    context.h[1] = 0xEFCDAB89;
    context.h[2] = 0x98BADCFE;
    context.h[3] = 0x10325476;

    // Store message length in bits
    context.totalSize = length * 8;
}

function md4Update(context, data) {
    // Append the `0x80` byte to data
    data = new Uint8Array([...data, 0x80]);

    // Add `0x00` bytes to align to 64-byte blocks (minus 8 bytes for the length)
    const padLen = (64 - ((data.length + 8) % 64)) % 64;
    const padding = new Uint8Array(padLen);
    data = new Uint8Array([...data, ...padding]);

    // Append the original message length as a 64-bit little-endian integer
    const lengthBytes = new Uint8Array(8);
    const tempView = new DataView(lengthBytes.buffer);
    tempView.setUint32(0, context.totalSize, true); // Lower 32 bits
    data = new Uint8Array([...data, ...lengthBytes]);

    // Split data into 64-byte chunks and push to buffer
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 64) {
        context.buffer.push(data.slice(i, i + 64));
    }
}

function md4Final(context) {
    md4ProcessBlock(context);

    // Finalise and copy digest as LE
    new DataView(context.digest.buffer).setUint32(0, context.h[0], true);
    new DataView(context.digest.buffer).setUint32(4, context.h[1], true);
    new DataView(context.digest.buffer).setUint32(8, context.h[2], true);
    new DataView(context.digest.buffer).setUint32(12, context.h[3], true);
}

function md4ProcessBlock(context) {
    for (const chunk of context.buffer) {
        let a = context.h[0],
            b = context.h[1],
            c = context.h[2],
            d = context.h[3];

        const x = new Uint32Array(new Uint8Array(chunk).buffer);

        // Round 1
        a = FF(a, b, c, d, x[0], 3);
        d = FF(d, a, b, c, x[1], 7);
        c = FF(c, d, a, b, x[2], 11);
        b = FF(b, c, d, a, x[3], 19);
        a = FF(a, b, c, d, x[4], 3);
        d = FF(d, a, b, c, x[5], 7);
        c = FF(c, d, a, b, x[6], 11);
        b = FF(b, c, d, a, x[7], 19);
        a = FF(a, b, c, d, x[8], 3);
        d = FF(d, a, b, c, x[9], 7);
        c = FF(c, d, a, b, x[10], 11);
        b = FF(b, c, d, a, x[11], 19);
        a = FF(a, b, c, d, x[12], 3);
        d = FF(d, a, b, c, x[13], 7);
        c = FF(c, d, a, b, x[14], 11);
        b = FF(b, c, d, a, x[15], 19);

        // Round 2
        a = GG(a, b, c, d, x[0], 3);
        d = GG(d, a, b, c, x[4], 5);
        c = GG(c, d, a, b, x[8], 9);
        b = GG(b, c, d, a, x[12], 13);
        a = GG(a, b, c, d, x[1], 3);
        d = GG(d, a, b, c, x[5], 5);
        c = GG(c, d, a, b, x[9], 9);
        b = GG(b, c, d, a, x[13], 13);
        a = GG(a, b, c, d, x[2], 3);
        d = GG(d, a, b, c, x[6], 5);
        c = GG(c, d, a, b, x[10], 9);
        b = GG(b, c, d, a, x[14], 13);
        a = GG(a, b, c, d, x[3], 3);
        d = GG(d, a, b, c, x[7], 5);
        c = GG(c, d, a, b, x[11], 9);
        b = GG(b, c, d, a, x[15], 13);

        // Round 3
        a = HH(a, b, c, d, x[0], 3);
        d = HH(d, a, b, c, x[8], 9);
        c = HH(c, d, a, b, x[4], 11);
        b = HH(b, c, d, a, x[12], 15);
        a = HH(a, b, c, d, x[2], 3);
        d = HH(d, a, b, c, x[10], 9);
        c = HH(c, d, a, b, x[6], 11);
        b = HH(b, c, d, a, x[14], 15);
        a = HH(a, b, c, d, x[1], 3);
        d = HH(d, a, b, c, x[9], 9);
        c = HH(c, d, a, b, x[5], 11);
        b = HH(b, c, d, a, x[13], 15);
        a = HH(a, b, c, d, x[3], 3);
        d = HH(d, a, b, c, x[11], 9);
        c = HH(c, d, a, b, x[7], 11);
        b = HH(b, c, d, a, x[15], 15);

        context.h[0] += a;
        context.h[1] += b;
        context.h[2] += c;
        context.h[3] += d;
    }
}



Here's how to call the function:
let input_string = new TextEncoder().encode('hello world');
let digest = md4Compute(input_string, input_string.length);

Note that this will return a Uint8Array so if you want to return a hex value, you can do the following:
Array.from(digest, i => i.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')


In md4ProcessBlock you do
for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    x[i] = letoh32(x[i]);
}

but letoh32 expects two arguments, the second being offset
const letoh32 = (buffer, offset) => {
    return (
        (buffer[offset] |
            (buffer[offset + 1] << 8) |
            (buffer[offset + 2] << 16) |
            (buffer[offset + 3] << 24)) >>>
        0
    );
};

So, it will be undefined

Ahh thanks for the correction. The code has now been updated to use the appropriate LETOH32() function which takes in one parameter. I've rerun the code and it still gives the same error.

@trwartek You should be getting a different error now. "RangeError: source array is too long". The error happens in the digest.set(context.digest.slice(0, 16)); line. But there are other issues with your code as well, and i do not know if they are relevant. For example md4Update takes 2 arguments, but you call it with 3 always. You pass it length or paddingSize but that part is never used in the code, and it might be important ?

Thanks for that! I have posted the amended code as an update below. But now we get an incorrect output.
